# Plot Image Hotpot with onclick validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i need to create image hot spot type question . administrator upload image and plot some area.
in user part the question image displayable to user with out plots. based on user click he clicked on same location or not . we need to find out

is any of predefined api which is suitable for my requirement .or any suggestions  to solve 
my problem.
my requirement is similar to 
http://articulate-community.s3.amazonaws.com/jeanette/Hotspot/PublishedSample/quiz.html

this type.

Thanks in advance

---

i am getting positions but i am getting problem mouse down and re size at a time .can any one help me that please check the link 

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/Ju5cA/#base)

```
var plotHotspot = function (e) {
    console.debug(e);

        spotCount++;

        var $hotspot = $('<div id="hotspot_' + spotCount + '"></div>').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'block',
            'left': (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) - (e.data.x / 2),
            'top': (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) - (e.data.y / 2),
            'height': e.data.y,
            'width': e.data.x,
            'background': 'url(' + config.icon + ')',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        }).resizable({ handles: "n, e, s, w, se, sw, nw, ne" },{
helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});
        simulateHandleClick($hotspot, 's', e.pageX, e.pageY);
        $hotspot.draggable();

        $imageContainer.append($hotspot);


        $hotspots = $hotspots.add($hotspot);`enter code here`

        $hotspot.on('click', initSpotConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
var $hotspot = $('<div id="hotspot_' + spotCount + '"></div>').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'block',
            'left': (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) - (e.data.x / 2),
            'top': (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) - (e.data.y / 2),
            'height': e.data.y,
            'width': e.data.x,
            'background': 'url(' + config.icon + ')',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        }).resizable({ handles: "n, e, s, w, se, sw, nw, ne" },{
helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});
```

and use trigger event for mousedown+ dragging at a time

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation you should create array with objects ex.:

```
var positions = [{
    startX: 100,
    startY: 100,
    endX: 150,
    endY: 150,
    type: 'some are 1'
},...];
```

//and then check it with mouse position relete to this element

```
var x = evt.pageX - $('#element').offset().left
var y = evt.pageY - $('#element').offset().top
```

Comment: max i am getting position but i am getting problem on mouse down re size selection at a time problem can you see once.please provide me any suggestions. please see the link http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/Ju5cA/

Comment: I didn't understend the problem you want to make icons not resizable?

Comment: i used icon for just identify space.i want when click+drag the hotspot width and height must re size according to the user dragging.but now it is not allowing at at time increase size.it is allowing re size hotspot div  after click .at a time both is not working